# Вывести все картинки в wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

Не знаю сможет ли здесь кто нибудь помочь, но больше спросить не где.

Требуется вывести все картинки в wordpress с информацией из произвольных полей, которые были созданы с помощью Advanced Custom Fields для вложений.

http://ssmaker.ru/870500b7.jpg

С выводом картинок вроде бы разобрался (не факт что правильно, но работает).

```
<?php
    $attachments = get_children( array('post_parent' => get_the_ID(), 'post_type' => 'attachment', 'post_mime_type' =>'image') );
    foreach ( $attachments as $attachment_id => $attachment ) {
       $image_attributes = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $attachment_id, 'full' );
       echo '<img src="' . $image_attributes[0] . '" width="' . $image_attributes[1] . '" height="' . $image_attributes[2] . '">';
    }
?>
```

Однако как прикрутить данные из произвольных полей?